# Sort a dictionary by multiple keys that represent the same value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, in each dictionary is a date (`datetime.datetime` objects), but in some cases it is associated with the key `"created_at"` and in other cases `"notification_timestamp"`.

```
data = [{'foo':'bar', 'created_at':'00:15:20 04/05/2019'},{'foo2':'bar2', 'notification_timestamp':'00:35:20 04/05/2019'}]
```

I know that I could just rename the keys but I need an efficient/scalable solution to ordering this list by these keys.

I have tried `data = data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("created_at", "notification_timestamp"), reverse=True)` but it throws the following error:

```
Exception Type: KeyError at /v1/my_script
Exception Value: 'notification_timestamp'
```

presumably because not all the dictionaries have this key.

I am certain of the data types of my variables, the output of this script

```
for d in data:
    if d.get("created_at", False):         
        print("CREATED AT TYPE: ", type(d.get("created_at")))
    if d.get("notification_timestamp", False):
        print("notification_timestamp TYPE: ", type(d.get("notification_timestamp")))
```

is

```
CREATED AT TYPE:  <class 'datetime.datetime'>
notification_timestamp TYPE:  <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

All help is appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'foo':'bar', 'created_at':'00:15:20 04/05/2019'},{'foo2':'bar2', 'notification_timestamp':'00:35:20 04/05/2019'}]
data.sort(key=lambda x: x.get("created_at", x.get("notification_timestamp")))  #Thanks AbdulNiyasPM & h4z3
print(data)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could get like that, this is so helpful, thanks!

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me this error instead `'<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'`, but I know for a fact both values associated with the keys are `datetime.datetime`. Could this be a result of the get? when the key isn't present it returns a str perhaps? Is there a way t override that if so?

Comment: No I just printed the `type()` of each object and they are both `datetime.datetime`

Comment: @h4z3 is there a way to use `x.get()` in a more useful way? Can I put a `get` in a `get`?

Comment: Oh I am so sorry that was a typo...@AbdulNiyasPM @h4z3. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rakesh for showing me the possibility of using `x.get()` in this circumstance, I found a solution:

`data.sort(key=lambda x: x.get("created_at", x.get("notification_timestamp", None)), reverse=True)`